# Вариативность в python

Tags: python, discord-api

```
if messtart("Hello World"): #1
    await evy.delete_message(message)
    await evy.send_message(message.channel, "Привет МИР!")#2
```

Хочу сделать больше вариативности, например чтобы в сообщении 2 вместо одного варианта отсылаемого сообщения было два, три или более. Тоже самое и с запросом 1.
Проштудировав пару гайдов я смог найти решение)

Comment: вы хотите выбрать случайный элемент из списка из строк?

Comment: если думаете, что нашли решение, то можете его как свой ответ опубликовать https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer